# How I will check that the mongodb service is runing or not using terminal command?

Tags: command-line, bash, mongodb

I'm using mongodb database to save my application data into collection but by some reasons the mongodb connection is break and there is lot of problems occurs and I want to check the mongodb connection through terminal command. I searched for it and I found three commands which will be used but I'm confused that which command I have to use in the golang code.

Command 1. `pgrep mongod` this command will return me PID (process Id).

Command 2. `ps -ef | grep mongod`  this command will returns me `mongodb  15678     1  1 13:58 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Command 3. `ps -ef | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '` this command I found from the stackoverflow accepted answer and it may be returns 0, 1. if there is other value except 0 then your mongodb is running as the answer say you can see link of the question

link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561098/how-to-check-if-mongo-db-is-running-on-mac

Command 4. `service --status-all | grep mongod` will show me the mongod service with a signed like `[ + ], or [ - ]`. In the documentation they says that if the service with `[ + ]` the service is running and `[ - ]` the service is stopped. But on my localhost the mongod is running and it will show me `[ - ] mongod` when I execute this command. Why?

link:- https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-list-all-services-in-linux/

Please tell me that which Command I have to used to check that the mongodb is running or not I have to use that command in my golang code.

Comment: I think if you just want to check the service is running, you can do just use `systemctl status mongod.service` and then check the return code (though the name of the serivice you may have to change, i don't remember exactly what it is

Comment: @j-money Can we use this command for the code purpose will it return the status?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, it will print info about the service to `stdout`, but when a service isn't active it will give back a non-zero return value. Are you writing a bash script? Or in another language?

Comment: `pgrep -ax mongod` 
571 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Answer (score 0):

You could run something along the lines of

```
if pgrep -x mongodd
 then echo "ok"
 else echo "not ok"
fi
```

Comment: please check this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212538/check-mongodb-status-is-running-or-not) is this commands are right to do this